# Largest palindrome product of two 3 digit numbers

Tags: c, pointers, printf, iteration

It was probably already posted somewhere, since it's a project Euler problem, but, I don't have a problem solving the particular problem, though I do have a problem with a code I wrote, since I can't seem to find a mistake.

My guess is that I'm overseeing something at printing or at memorising values, but I am not certain. Anyways, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int x = 999, y = 999, z = 0, w = 0, a=0, *largest = a;
for (x; x > 99; x--){
    for (y; y > 99; y--){
        z = x*y;
        while (z != 0){
            w = w * 10;
            w = w + z % 10;
            z = z/10;
        }
        if (x*y == w){
            a = w;
            goto stop;
        }
        w = 0;
    }
}
stop: printf("%d\n", largest);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I know that a and largest and stuff aren't necessary, I was just testing a lot changing all kind of stuff, using pointers and what so not, so no need to pay a lot of attention to that part of the code.

Comment: It would be cleanest to set `w = 0;` before you go creating the reverse value of `z`, rather than doing it miles away at the end of the loop.  You could even use: `int w = 0; int z = x * y;` in the body of the `for` loop, limiting the scope of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code assigns the largest product's value in `a` but you are printing `largest` which is a pointer. Your program doesn't need the pointer `largest` at all.

Your code also doesn't work because you

- don't check if the largest is greater than previous one
- do not reset `y` to `999` in the inner loop.

With the above two fixes, it would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
int x = 999, y = 999, z = 0, w = 0, a=0;

for (x; x > 99; x--){
    for (y=999; y > 99; y--){
        z = x*y;
        while (z != 0){
            w = w * 10;
            w = w + z % 10;
            z = z/10;
        }
        if (x*y == w && a<x*y){
            a = w;
        }
        w = 0;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now what was happening, or at least I think I do. Apparently the y variable stayed the same once it reached 100. As for the largest, I know it was redundant, just started playing around since I couldn't figure stuff out

Comment: One more thing though, is the condition for a<x*y really necessary, if I break the loop as soon as it finds the palindrome? Never mind, I figured it out the second I posted, thanks :)

Comment: hehe..You can name a to largest if that makes it clear. This can be improved to break the loop earlier. For example, `101*101` (`10201`) is also matches your criteria. But that's not what you want. I'll leave it to you to improve further :)

Comment: Yeah, 998*998 is larger than 999*200 or something, didn't cross my mind that would happen until I pressed enter to post that comment :)
As for improving, don't think I'll spend too much time on this, trying to go through all(?) project Euler problems, even though it will take some time for me I believe :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by rakeb, you should use:
*largest = &a

Besides that, the reason you are not getting the correct answer is because your if statement is never true so 'a' will always stay 0.

Comment: I feel like that is what's happening, the thing is that I am not sure why that's so

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are assigning a int type to a int * type in the statement

```
 *largest=a;
```

make it *largest=&a;

Moreover while printing use the * operator before largest

```
stop: printf("%d\n", *largest);
```

Finally to add up your logic may be faulty as you check :

999X999  ,  999X998  , 999X997 and so on........

however 999*997 is less than 998*998 and hence your code may lead to a lower pallindrome number than possible.

Comment: Right, I just left the largest and a since I was desperate pretty much and was trying everything, I'll set them as they should be. This will continue returning 0's though.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to just print and end as soon as a number is palindrome? Not sure I get what you're saying

Comment: I am saying that your checking if 999X999 is pallindrome. Lets assume that its not.next you check if 998X999 is a pallindrome or not.Lets again assume its not a pallindrome . now comes the main part . You check if 999X997 is a pallindrome or not. However 999X998 gives a bigger number than 999X997. So you  are going on checking smaller numbers when there was already a larger number to check(998X998).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that when Blue Moon answered this question, didn't think it through I guess, thank you for noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

the posted code fails to cleanly compile.

Suggest always enabling all warnings when compiling

(for gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Fix the warnings, don't just try to hide them.

Then post the corrected code, if it still displays the problem

Comment: Had none of those in visual studio, using that for compiling till I get my linux drive back, sorry